# Organisation-produced references in JabRef

Tags: bibtex, jabref

Using Jabref and Libreoffice, via Jabref's 'OpenOffice connect' feature. I have a source that includes spaces and the word 'and' in a single author's name. Jabref parses this according to the usual rules - spaces separate first and last names, 'and' separating multiple authors. I have wrapped the name in an extra set of braces like so:

```
@Book{Innovation2011,
  Title                    = {ICAICT203A - Operate application software packages},
  Author                   = {{Innovation and Business Skills Australia}},
  Publisher                = {Australian Government},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Url                      = {https://training.gov.au/Training/Details/ICAICT203A}
}
```

Which causes it to be treated as one symbol in the reference list (it appears as "Innovation and Business Skills Australia" rather than "Innovation and Australia, B. S"). But, my in-text citations for it still appear as "(Innovation & Australia, 2011)" rather than "(Innovation and Business Skills Australia, 2011)".

This also happens with, for example, this source, where the author is two words which don't comprise a person's name:

```
@Book{BlackwaterProjects2013,
  Title                    = {Certificate IV Training and Assessment Participant Manual - Design},
  Author                   = {{Blackwater Projects}},
  Year                     = {2013}
}
```

Is properly included in the reference list as "Blackwater Projects" rather than "Projects, B" (as it is without the extra braces), but the in-text references are "(Projects, 2013)". Using other fields such as 'organisation' instead of 'author' behaves the same way.

Is there a way to convince Jabref to use the full author name for in-text references for these sources?

Comment: JabRef doesn't do anything in terms of generating a bibliography: it's down to the tool you use to extract the data. I note that you are using LibreOffice, which could make this question off-topic for us: with (La)TeX you use BibTeX, Biber or very closely related tools to do the extraction, and they all 'know' that a braced name is 'left alone'. Can you describe the process you use in a bit more detail?

Comment: @JosephWright I use the 'connect to OpenOffice' function in Jabref, and click the 'Cite' and/or 'Cite in-text' buttons. As far as I know, this causes Jabref itself to do the extraction, because LibreOffice's referencing support is.. clunky. And, for example, Jabref has a function to rebuild the reference list according to what is actually cited in the document. If this is off-topic here, where would it be better? SuperUser?

Comment: Superuser currently has only [6 questions about JabRef](http://superuser.com/search?q=jabref+is%3Aquestion), don't know if there may be another site for asking. There had been a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/bugs/823/) about this, but it was closed without giving an answer. You get the same, faulty behaviour in JabRef's entry previewer, so it is probably the author tokenizer and the `\author` formatter which don't work correctly. In your bibliography you have probably the full name, or `First Last` so that you don't see this problem. Don't know a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since this question was raised, but it has been fixed in JabRef 3.3. (Yay!) I ran into the same problem more recently, and in the course of looking for a solution, found your question. I figured the lack of an answer was on account of most folks not using JabRef in connection with LibreOffice/OpenOffice, so I re-posed the question as a bug and changed the entity requiring citation to the JabRef developers themselves. Here's a link to the closed bug:

[JabRef curly braces bug marked closed](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/815)

[JabRef merged bug acknowledges fix](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/874)

To run JabRef 3.3 you'll need to have Java 8 installed.